# asp.net core mvc date format issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on an asp.net mvc core 2.0 application.

There is a part of an entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    ....
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? creation_date {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

Here is my viewmodel class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ....
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? creation_date {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

My MyController's action method is very trivial: I load Entity from database and i create a MyModel instance. I assign each field and i pass the viewmodel instance to View.

Here is the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="Edit">
...
<input asp-for="creation_date" class="formulaire" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
...
</form>
```

As you can see, i always set a date format string: Day on 2 digits / Month on 2 digits / Year on 4 digits.

When i run the application, if i type 01/02/2003 in date input, i will get 02/01/2003 in database. I do not understand why....

Thanks

Comment: Because the culture on your server expects dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. Change the culture in your `web.config` file (and as a side note, it needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` to work correctly if your wanting to render the browsers HTML-5 datepicker)

Comment: I am working with asp.net core mvc2. There is no web.config and how can i do if a have differents formats in my application ?

Comment: You can do it in `ConfigureServices` (see [this article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/22/request-culture-asp-net-core/))

Comment: But not sure what you mean by _different formats in my application_

Comment: What happens when you read the value back? Does it show correctly? You have set DisplayFormat attribute which would format the date as you want (DateTime is format-agnostic). But database does not necessarily uses the same format. It will store it as datetime datatype on server which may not follow the display format you want. But if you read back on client side, it will give you same DateTime you saved.